# Create directory with timestamp of newest files

Tags: linux, directory, date, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory based on the timestamp of the 2 newest files in a directory and then copy those 2 files in to the newly created directory.  SO for example

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 24 12:01 a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 24 12:01 b
```

I want to create a directory called `20190924` and copy `a` and `b` into the directory which are the newest files in the current directory

Comment: What if those two files have different dates in their timestamp?

Comment: The scenerio i'm working on is that only 2 files are generated everyday

Comment: How does that answer @sudodus' question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This zsh script will pick up the two newest (plain) files in the current directory, gather the modification timestamp of the most recent one, convert that timestamp to YYYYmmdd format, create the directory, then copy those two newest files into that directory:

```zsh
#!/bin/zsh

newest2=( *(.om[1,2]) )
dsec=$( stat -c %Y "${newest2[1]}" )
dnam=$( date -d @"$dsec" +%Y%m%d )
mkdir "$dnam"
cp -- "${newest2[@]}" "$dnam"
```

The first line, assigning `newest2`, expands the `*` wildcard with a qualifier (in parenthesis). The qualifier asks for:

- `.` -- plain files
- `om` -- ordered by modification time (newest to oldeset)
- `[1,2]` -- slice the list to include only elements 1 through 2

We then ask `stat` for the modification time in seconds of the newest file; that date is passed in to GNU `date`, who returns the directory name in the format we want. After creating the directory, the `cp` command copies the two files into that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are assuming that you want the name of the folder extracted from the *first* file:

#### Create the directory

```
dir="$(mkdir -p $(ls -ltp --full-time | grep -v / | awk '{print $6}' | sed -n '2p' | sed 's/-//g'))"
```

---

List only files `grep -v /`, sorted by time `lt`, show the full time (so we have the date) `--full-time`.

```
ls -ltp --full-time | grep -v /
```

---

Choose the column of dates

```
awk '{print $6}'
```

---

Retrieve the second line (the first line shows the number of files) that correspond to the first file and delete the dashes:

```
sed -n '2p' | sed 's/-//g'
```

#### Copy the files

```
cp $(ls -ltp --full-time | grep -v / | awk '{print $9}' | sed -n '2,3p' | tr '\n' ' ') "${dir}/"
```

---

List only files `grep -v /`, sorted by time `lt`, show the full time (so we have the date) `--full-time`.

```
ls -ltp --full-time | grep -v /
```

---

Retrieve the names of the files:

```
awk '{print $9}'
```

---

Choose the first and the second file

```
sed -n '2,3p'
```

---

Substitute the the new line for a space, so we can perform a copy in one line.

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

The command would look like this

```
cp x z 20190924/
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however the copy part does not work.  The directory gets created but its empty